# Javascript get id

Tags: javascript, get

```
function check(id){
    var _id = document.getElementById(id);
    url = "test.php?check=1&id=" + _id;
}
```

i want the id in the url it's working but without the id that is in the check('123');

It's for an innerHTML to load something

hope you can help me with getting the id

Greetings

Comment: Can you post more of your code so we can understand whatyou are trying to achieve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `document.getElementId()` function returns an object value based on the identifier string (ID) that you supply; therefore if you have an element on your page with the id of `foo` then you call

```
document.getElementById("foo");
```

to return the *object* for that element, so that you can manipulate it (changing styles, or attributes etc).

If you want to insert the id into the URL of the test.php page, why not simply pass the identifier string of the element that you pass in with the function?:

```
function check(id){
    url = "test.php?check=1&id=" + id;
}
```

Then calling

```
check("123");
```

will set the `url` variable to `test.php?check=1&id=123`

Answer (score 2):

```
var _id = document.getElementById(id).id;
```

Comment: Either the OP is unaware that .id will = the input to getElementById  or this isn't what the OP wants, which is admittedly rather hard to decipher.

Comment: hi there,

now i don't get anything before it gave me ?check=1&id=null

i need to get ?check=1&id=123

thanks for the quick answer